# passing xml values as url values(GET)

Tags: php, xml, url, get

I can post values in url without form...(`filename.php&key1=value1&key2=value2`)
and I can run the file

what if the key and value is posted through XML

How to pass the values in url and run the file??

ex:
<    key1    >value1<    /key1    >
<    key2    >value2<    /key2    >

Comment: In my opinion it's hard to understand what you want to do. Show us XML example, tell how URL should look then and we could try to help You :)

Answer (score 1):

If the URL has a valid format, the nature of the data does not matter. Simply use [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode) as usual.

However, the URL is not a suitable place to transmit large amounts of data since it has a size limit and such limit is not even universal.

Answer (score 0):

An URL in a XML-file is exactly the same as any other URL defined as [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier). So, to pass values from XML to some script, you just append those values to the URL as accustomed.

Values passed via an URL, are accessible as $_GET-variables in PHP. You also don't need something like `$_POST=$_REQUEST;`, because `$_REQUEST` is *[An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)*